# Adding rows to a SQL Server database from data entered by user in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Data (Name, Sur-Name, Score,Avg) VALUES ('" + fName + "','" + sName + "','" + lblScore.Text + "','" + lblAvg.Text + "');");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", fName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sur-Name", sName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", lblScore.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Avg", lblAvg.Text);

try
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    lblData.Text = exc.Message;              
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

The error I keep getting is a runtime saying

> Incorrect syntax near '-'. Incorrect syntax near '-'.

I used the try catch just so page would load and my scores show but the label says this Incorrect syntax as well, I was wondering could anyone please help me with what I am doing wrong

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I think `Sur-Name` breaks your query. Use it with square brackets like `[Sur-Name]`

But more important, please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. I see you tried to use but you never declare your parameter names in your query.

Also `DATA` might be a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) on future versions of SQL Server. You might need to use with also like `[DATA]`

Consider to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Data] (Name, [Sur-Name], Score, Avg)
                       VALUES (@Name, @SurName, @Score, @Avg)";
   cmd.Connection = connection;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", fName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", sName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", lblScore.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Avg", lblAvg.Text);

   try
   {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
        lblData.Text = exc.Message;
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to mix concatenated queries with parametrized. Always use parametrized queries, It will save you from SQL Injection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Data] (Name, [Sur-Name], Score,Avg) VALUES (
                                  @Name, @SurName, @Score, @Avg)");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", fName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", sName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", lblScore.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Avg", lblAvg.Text);
```

Also consider enclosing your connection and command object in `using` statement.

As @Soner has mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22665570/961113), use Square brackets for `Data` and `Sur-Name`